# ASP.NET MVC model to JS object and back to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to replace server side action call by javascript action call.

I have action in controller

```
public ActionResult MyTest(TestObj obj)
{
    return PartialView("test2");
}
```

And my action call in view looks like this right now:

```
<div id="TestDiv">
    @Html.Action("MyTest", "Home", new { obj = Model })
</div>
```

So I tried to replace it by this js function

```
<script>
    var jsModel =@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));   @*'@serializer.Serialize(Model)';*@
    function newHope() {
        var url = '@Url.Action("MyTest", "Home")';
        $('#TestDiv').load(url, { obj: jsModel });
    }
</script>
```

However all obj properties have default values when I'm sending obj via js and everything is OK when it's send from `@Html.Action`.

Any idea why biding not working with js model?

Comment: may be you need to pass ``@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))`` like a parameter to ``newHope``

Comment: Try this: `var jsModel ='@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
<script>
    var jsModel =@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));   @*'@serializer.Serialize(Model)';*@
    function newHope() {
        var url = '@Url.Action("MyTest", "Home")';
        $('#TestDiv').load(url, '{ obj: ' +jsModel +'}');

    }
</script>
```

You need to stringify the entire payload so that it can be deserialezed properly. I have not tried it, so you might need to tweak it a bit.

Comment: same empty object as in my case ( empty not null)